# I need to know workflow's id

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I'm using WF 4.0

How can I know the id of the current workflow? while i need to save it to DB and retrive it in two activities?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From within the workflow or outside of it?

Outside, the WorkflowApplication has an [Id property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.id.aspx).

Inside, it depends.  I usually get it from the [NativeActivityContext.WorkflowInstanceId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activitycontext.workflowinstanceid.aspx) property.  But I always extend NativeActivity.

Comment: @Sofy: Yes, it did work.  Both are the Ids of the workflows as they are stored in the database.  If you tested this by checking the database for the Ids, realize that there are *many* tables, and that you should not mess with them; you should let the WorkflowApplication store and load the workflow.